# How to run a python made .exe on a repeated schedule in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows

I have a GUI based.exe, which I made using Python auto-py-to-exe (one folder method), and I want the application to run up after every 10 minutes or so.
It is working when I click on it manually.

I have tried using task scheduler in windows to do that, but it is not exactly executing the application as I cannot see anything on screen. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Does the exe run when manually open the file because task scheduler should work.

Comment: Yes, it does open normally when clicked manually. @It_is_Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not answering directly the question but maybe still solving your problems. To run python scripts on schedule i usually write a .bat script that gets executed by task scheduler.
The bat script has to have the full length python path for the invocation and the full path of the .py file.

I think it's possible to use the same strategy to run exe files, so you could try using a .bat that targets your exe instead of targetting the exe directly in the task scheduler.

Comment: Thanks, though I would not have any experience writing a .bat script, but I can look this up, unless you have a resource to share on 'how to write my own batch file'.

Comment: An example of one of my .bat is "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "D:\Python\yyyyy\main.py". All in the same line, with the ""